# Storing the results of a query in a variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, query

I have an object "`Case`" with the fields "`Contact_Search_Name__c`" and "`CaseNumber`" and I have an object "`Case_Notes__c`" with the field "`Contact_Name__C`" basically I am trying to use this query                      `SELECT CaseNumber FROM case WHERE Contact_Search_Name__c = Contact_Name__C` to store in a variable. I then want to populate the Master-Detail field "`Case__c`" in "`object Case_Notes__c`" with the contents of this variable.

Comment: OK. So what's your question? What did you try? A trigger? Maybe you could add your code to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want(if I understood correctly of course) by doing the following:

```
List<Case_Notes__c> cns = [SELECT Contact_Name__c FROM Case_Notes__c];
List<Case> cnrs = [SELECT CaseNumber, Contact_Search_Name__c FROM Case WHERE Contact_Search_Name__c IN :cns];
```

So you make a list of *Case_Notes__c*, then you retrieve *CaseNumber*s from *Case* which has *Contact_Search_Name__c* in the first list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the Case__c field on the CAse_Notes__c object with the contents of the CaseNumber field if the CaseNumber field is not the ID field for the Case__c object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to query id as well in SOQL query.

SELECT id, CaseNumber FROM case WHERE Contact_Search_Name__c =: Contact_Name__C

Store this record to a Case Objext instance and In Case_Notes__c  for Case__c map this instance record Id.

In Salesforce we always need to map the parent record id to child object to establish a relationship.